# How to turn on C++0x of Intel C++ Compiler 12.1.2

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, c++11, intel

I installed the latest version of Intel C++ Compiler v12.1.2 on Arch Linux 3.2.1. When I used icpc to compile my C++ file

```
icpc -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=gnu++0x -o obj/main.o src/main.cpp -c
```

or

```
icpc -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=c++0x -o obj/main.o src/main.cpp -c
```

A warning popped out

```
Warning #2928: the __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__ macro is disabled when using GNU version 4.6 with the c++0x option
```

My main.cpp contains many C++0x features such as rvalue references, auto, etc. But the Intel compiler did not work in C++0x mode. How to turn on its C++0x features?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to fight my way through this, but a quick solution seems to be:

1. Install libstdc++4.5 (or earlier)
2. compile with `icpc -gcc-name=gcc-4.5 -std=c++0x`

The problem is that Intel compilers do not support all the C++0x features that GNU compilers do starting from version 4.6. This causes incompatibilities with GNU libstdc++ headers since at present all the C++0x features are protected by a unique macro `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` and cannot be enabled or disabled singularly.

Answer (score 2):

Check [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/c0x-features-supported-by-intel-c-compiler/). It seems that C++0x is not *fully* supported

Comment: Of course no compiler can support all the C++0x features at this moment, but most mainstream compilers can support some of them. I'm sure Intel C++ Compiler 12.1.2 definitely supports rvalue references. Now the problem, how to enable it?

Comment: I recall I used `icc` a couple a few months ago and I had to resign from C++0x. But it rather won't help you much : )

Comment: @JackyLee : The same link also answers that -- "*On Windows environment when using Intel C++ compiler with Visual Studio 2010\*, the C++0x features supported by Visual C++ 2010 are enabled by default. Use `"/Qstd=c++0x"` to turn on the support for all other cases. On Linux or Mac OS X environment use `"-std=c++0x"`.*"