# clang support of aggregation initialization on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, c++11, clang, clang++

I'm trying to compile C++11 list congregation initialization on clang++ on mac.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    list<string> aList = {"abc", "def", "xyz"};
}
```

This is the command for the compilation.

```
clang++-mp-3.1 -std=c++11 iterator.cpp
```

I got no matching constructor error.

```
iterator.cpp:7:23: error: no matching constructor for initialization of
  'std::list<string>'
std::list<string> aList = {"abc", "def", "xyz"};
                  ^       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I tried with XCode

```
clang -v
Apple clang version 4.1 (tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2
Thread model: posix
```

I also tried with clang++ from port

```
clang++-mp-3.1 -v
clang version 3.1 (branches/release_31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2
Thread model: posix
```

I got the same result. What might be wrong?

[clang's support of C++ 11 lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13351032/clangs-support-of-c-11-lambda)

Comment: Have you used the `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++0x` flag?

Comment: @H2CO3 : I have that flag on.

Comment: clang from svn trunk compiles your code.

Comment: That's not aggregate initialization. That's *uniform* initialization via an initializer_list constructor.

Comment: Also, what version of your standard library implementation are you using?

Comment: @NicolBolas - The error message shows "/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/", how can I switch to proper library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried [icc](http://software.intel.com/en-us/c-compilers), got the same error. I guess the issue is with the template not the compiler. icc uses existing template /usr/include/c++/4.2.1 and the implementation doesn't support c++11 fully.

I tried gcc 4.8 from port

```
sudo port install gcc48
```

It works fine

```
/opt/local/bin/g++-mp-4.8 -std=c++11 Iterator.cpp
```

[How to turn on C++0x of Intel C++ Compiler 12.1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938325/how-to-turn-on-c0x-of-intel-c-compiler-12-1-2)