# Simple example of c++11 shared_ptr won't compile

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to get Intel C++ 14.0.2 compiler to use the C++11 options. I've got this really simple code (which I simplified from: [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr/)):

```c++
// shared_ptr constructor example
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct C {int* data;};

int main () {
  std::shared_ptr<int> p1;

  std::cout << "use_count:\n";
  std::cout << "p1: " << p1.use_count() << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

I tried to compile this with the Intel C++ 14.0.2 compiler but I just get these errors:

```
$ icpc --std=c++11 test.cpp
test.cpp(8): error: namespace "std" has no member "shared_ptr"
    std::shared_ptr<int> p1;
         ^

test.cpp(8): error: type name is not allowed
    std::shared_ptr<int> p1;
                    ^

test.cpp(8): error: identifier "p1" is undefined
    std::shared_ptr<int> p1;
                         ^

compilation aborted for test.cpp (code 2)
```

(I've also tried using `-std=c++11`, but got the same errors.) Am I using the `shared_ptr` wrong? Am I invoking the compiler wrong? This seems to be about as simple an example as I can come up with to illustrate this problem.

Comment: Nope [the code is correct](http://ideone.com/DIUxLL), it's your compiler

Comment: Try `-std=c++11` instead of `--std=c++11`. Both GCC and clang use a single `-`, so maybe ICC does too.

Comment: @awesomeyi Thanks for confirming my suspicions. At least I'm not batty!

Comment: @Praetorian I've tried that as well, but got the same response.

Comment: For ICC it is -std=c++11

Comment: It seems Intel's compiler doesn't ship with a C++11 standard library, yet. Also, trying to use libstdc++ or libc++ doesn't seem to be too successful as these want some macros to be defined.

Comment: Mh ... so using <tr1/memory> (assuming it supports C++ TR1) should not work?

Comment: try the -std=c++0x flag

Comment: @DominikSelzer no that didn't work. You'd think that Intel would support this already.

Comment: @lizusek Nope, that didn't work either.

Comment: @Jermey I have no ICC at hand right now. We use it on a few compute servers at my work. I can try and test tomorrow morning. If you need this feature you can still use boost.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938325/how-to-turn-on-c0x-of-intel-c-compiler-12-1-2

Comment: @DominikSelzer I'm trying to avoid having to install/use boost if necessary. That may not be possible.

Comment: compiling on linux?  Did you check the `tr` namespaces?

Comment: @Yakk I'm compiling on a Mac. I have not tried the `tr1` namespace. Should I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shared_ptr` isn't listed as one of the supported features for version 14.0 in Intel's list of supported features:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/c0x-features-supported-by-intel-c-compiler

Comment: I was afraid of that. :(